# cpp simulating mouseclick also moves the cursor

Tags: windows, winapi, input, simulate

I have this following cpp script:

```
INPUT Inputs[3] = { 0 };

Inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Inputs[0].mi.dx = 0; 
Inputs[0].mi.dy = 0; 
Inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;

Inputs[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Inputs[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

Inputs[2].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
Inputs[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

SendInput(3, Inputs, sizeof(INPUT));
```

which should simulate a mouse press, and it works, but it also always moves the cursor to a specific position, even if I dont have this

```
Inputs[0].mi.dx = 0; 
Inputs[0].mi.dy = 0;
```

part. I want it just to click but not moving the cursor

Comment: What operating system are you using?  What framework are you using?  More tags would get the right eyes on this.

Comment: And posting a minimal reproducible code will get you help, not just eyes.

Comment: Why have the first `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` input at all if you don't want to move the cursor?

Comment: If you want to click a button, but not move the mouse cursor, you could consider posting a windows message to the control you want to click instead of simulating input.

Comment: Or continue to use SendInput, but simply move the mouse cursor back after the click.

Comment: Or use `GetCursorPos()` to get the current cursor position and use that to populate the coordinates.

Comment: If you don't want to move the cursor, then don't specify `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE`, simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse cursor moves because you requested the mouse cursor to move by setting the `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE` flag in the first `INPUT` structure.

If you don't want the mouse to move, remove the entire first `INPUT` structure. If, on the other hand, you want to inject a mouse move event, but not actually move the mouse, remove the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag.